# Xamarin app doesn't debug on Android device

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

I am developing Xamarin App on Visual Studio, and I want to debug the app on Android device, when deploying on debug mode on Visual Studio, the app gets installed but when trying to open this error shows up on Visual Studio.

> Couldn't connect to with logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0
>
> Couldn't connect to the debugger. You can see more details in Xamarin diagnostic output

The app does work when deploying on release.

Comment: Could you please post the  Xamarin diagnostic output just as the hint mentioned?

Comment: I cant find xamarin output, ive search online of where is the log but just cant find it.

Comment: You can check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output